# How to use drools 6.1 final version on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, drools

We have been using Drools guvnor 5.5.0 on JBoss 7.0. Now we want to use drools 6.1 final version. We have deployed all the jar files but unable to access UI as could not find war file. We got war file for 5.5.0 version from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/drools/guvnor-distribution-wars/5.5.0.Final/ but unable to find same for 6.1.final version. Tried to use kie-drools-wb-distribution but not working.

Can anyone tell the way to use drools 6.1 version or to get the UI to create rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing [Goodbye Guvnor. Hello Drools Workbench](http://planet.jboss.org/post/goodbye_guvnor_hello_drools_workbench).

> Along with the functional and feature changes we have restructured the
>   Guvnor github repository to better reflect our new architecture.
>   Guvnor has historically been the web application for Drools. It was a
>   composition of editors specific to Drools, a back-end repository and a
>   simplistic asset management system.
>
> Things are now different.
>
> For **Drools 6.0** the web application has been extensively re-written to
>   use UberFire that provides a generic Workbench environment, a Metadata
>   Engine, Security Framework, a VFS API and clustering support.
>
> Guvnor has become a generic asset management framework providing
>   common services for generic projects and their dependencies. Drools
>   use of both UberFire and Guvnor has born the **Drools Workbench**.

**Drools Workbench (drools-wb)**

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-wb

**Drools Workbench** is the end product for people looking for a web application that is composed of all Drools related editors, screens and services. It is equivalent to the old **Guvnor**.

You can download from http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip

Se also: [Workbench Installation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html#wb.Installation)

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. From where can we download workbench war file like we used guvnor war file?